# Adding shadow to UITextView makes text expand out of UITextViewFrame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, shadow

[image]

I have an UITextView and I wanna add shadow to it. The code I use is :

```
textview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
textview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0,height: 2.0)
textview.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
textview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
textview.layer.masksToBounds = false
textview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

This code adds the shadow and makes the corners rounded but it also makes the text inside UITextView  get out of textview frame. 
I tried adding

```
textview.clipToBounds = true
```

this sets the text inside but it removes the shadow. I've also tried setting :

```
textview.layer.maskToBounds = true
textview.clipToBounds = false
```

and yet the problem repeats itself.
I read somewhere here that I should set

```
textview.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

It does nothing, just like seting it to false does nothing. 
So if anybody has any idea what would work, help me because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately if you use `textview.clipsToBounds = true` than your shadows will not be visible.

What I recommend you do is set `textview.clipsToBounds = true` and the insert another `UIView` below the `textview` which has same frame as the `textview` and draw shadow and corner radius on that `UIView`.

With that text from `UITextView` will not overflow it's bounds and you will have the shadow and corner radius visible...

Comment: As far as I read online this is probably the best solution for this scenario.